# jQuery code only works in browser's editor but not when in script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

I have been finding it difficult to find out why my Jquery code does not work when inserted in a `<script></script>` tag but works when executed in my browser's editor. The below code has no errors and works fine only when Jquery script is executed in my browser's editor but doesn't when used in a script tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Delete data</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div><font color="#000"><b>Aaron</b></font></b>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start comment_buts" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">
        <span class="mr-3"><a href="#"><font color="red">Like</font></a></span>
        <span class="mr-3 comment_reply" id="mention_aaron">Reply</span>
        <span class="mr-3 comment_del_but" id="del_15841889572020Aaroncmidb1">Delete</span>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var post_id = "b71ShOv5imgidb1"; // $_GET['post_id'];
    </script>
    <script src="delete.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**delete.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment_del_but').click(function(){
        var el = this;
        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split("_");

        // id
        var deleteid = splitid[1];

        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php?p_id='+post_id,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id:deleteid },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == 1) {
                    $(el).closest('.comment_to_del').fadeOut(500, function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Ops! Something went wrong, please try again');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php 
    // connect to db
    include 'db.php';

    if (isset($_GET['p_id']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $post_id = $_GET['p_id']; // post id
        $comment_id = $_POST['id']; // comment id

        // select comment
        $select_comment = "SELECT comment FROM users_post_comments WHERE comment_id = ? AND for_post_id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $select_comment)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $comment_id, $post_id);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                // fetch results
            }

            // if comment exist
            if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
                $delete_comment = "DELETE FROM users_post_comments WHERE comment_id = ? AND for_post_id = ?";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $delete_comment);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $comment_id, $post_id);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                echo 1;
                // echo "deleted successful";
            } else {
                echo 0;
            }
        }
        // close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    // close db connection
    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: You're POSTing the AJAX, but trying to get the data from `$_GET` ..?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in browser console to see if the js file is loading or not when using with script tag?

Comment: Yes it is! I also inserted `console.log("checking script");` after my click function but get no errors @palaѕн

Comment: Am using PHP to get post_id which works fine. I just inserted the id there in order not to insert `$_GET['post_id'];` instead @Teemu

Comment: In `delete.js`, `post_id` is not defined on this line `url: 'delete.php?p_id='+post_id,`. What's the resulting URL it's trying to call?

Comment: the variable `post_id` is been gotten by my PHP code. Everything works fine the problem here is that my Jquery code does not work when inserted in a script tag but works when executed in my browser's editor. I have been having a hard time because of this. Nothing seems to be wrong but my code doesn't work when included into a page @tao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I just replaced

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment_del_but').click(function(){
```

with

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.comment_del_but',function(){
```

and my code now works fine. I think this might be because of the version of JQuery am using, maybe. Anyway, thanks for your support.